# Animating a view inside a UITableViewCell to expand it outside the cell bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make an animation that takes a view inside a cell animate on tap, to make it expand outside the bounds of the cell itself. This is my attempt:

```
if let viewToAnimate = viewToAnimate{
            let offset = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: tableView.bounds.origin.y - viewToAnimate.bounds.origin.y)
            let scale = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/viewToAnimate.frame.size.width
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
                let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset.horizontal, y: offset.vertical)
                viewToAnimate.transform = scaleTransform.concatenating(translateTransform)
            }, completion: { (finished) in
            })
        }
```

The problem is that the animation isn't working at all, so I'm wondering if this is the right approach or if I'm totally on the wrong track.

Comment: Any reason why you are using transforms here rather than simply changing viewToAnimate's frame?

Comment: @Sparky the idea is to use the affine transforms to be able to revert the animation later with a simple transform identity. The target is to animate the view contained in the cell to move it to the top of the page, expanding it and adapting to take the whole screen width, then be able to revert the whole process

Comment: Yes, but you could do that by reverting the frame to its original value too. When I'm back at my desk I can send you some code on this.